# Git merge without remote branch

Tags: git, git-merge

After doing a GIT merge from branch A to branch B I typically diff the merge by comparing the (merged) local branch with the (non merged) remote branch:

```
git checkout mybranch
git pull mybranch
<do merge>
git difftool --dir-diff origin/mybranch mybranch
```

This works well.  But if I have a local branch which does not have a remote branch I can't do this.

What is the best way to do a clean diff in this case?

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity, but I would assume that you are checking the diff between the two branches in order to make sure that your local changes are the same as the remote ones and that the merge + pull commands have worked properly (thus proving that your local repo is the same as remote), right?

Comment: I'm doing the diff as a general review before doing a push to remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words: You want to compare the last commit before the merge with current commit.

```
git difftool -d HEAD^..
```

The `^` refers to the first parent of a merge commit, in this case `HEAD` (`^` is short for `^1`). The `..` is used to specify a range, and if either side is empty Git will use `HEAD`, so the above range is equivalent to `HEAD^..HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks.  Would that work for merges that don't have conflicts when Git just pulls in the changesets without a merge commit?

Comment: In case of a fast-forward pull, this method would only work if the pull consisted only of a single commit. In that scenario you should use the reflog as @Useless suggested. You could shorten the range description to `HEAD@{1}..` as I described in the answer.

Comment: Ok, or you can merge using `git merge otherbranch --no-ff` and then use the syntax in this answer.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, sure. Though I wouldn't change merge strategy just to be able to use this syntax...

Comment: Only issues I have with these approaches is that if there are no changes being merged the diff will list a difference between the last two heads even if not from the current merge.  Whereas the approach of diffing with remote doesn't have this drawback....

Comment: If it's about doing it programmatically or something, you could always go for something like: `old=$(git rev-parse HEAD); git merge something; git diff $old..HEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to alfunx's answer, you can use the reflog naming scheme to get the previous version of HEAD (ie, what HEAD used to be before the merge):

```
git difftool -d HEAD@{1}..HEAD
```

You can check `git reflog` to confirm that matches the commit expected. It's a bit less direct than the `HEAD^` syntax, but avoids any possible ambiguity about which parent of a multi-parent merge you're diffing against.